# how to count quantity hold in mysql based on 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, it's called shipping_details and shipping_resend

this is shipping_details table

```
+-----+-------------+------------+---------------+-------------+---------+
| id  | shipping_Id |  quantity  | quantity_send |  createdAt  | product |
+-----+-------------+------------+---------------+-------------+---------+
|   1 |         123 |          2 | 2             | 2021-02-02  | A       |
|   2 |         123 |          1 | NULL          | 2021-02-02  | B       |
+-----+-------------+------------+---------------+-------------+---------+
```

Explanation on table shipping_details :

1. when the users is doing transaction, the details of each product has appear on this table
2. `shipping_details.quantity` is the total of quantity for each product in his transaction
3. `shipping_details.quantity_send` is basically are the total of
   quantity which has been successful to be shipping in users,
   because sometimes for any other reason, the product can't sent it on full quantity,
   basically, quantity_send is from
   sum(shipping_resend.quantity) on shipping_resend_table for each product

this is `shipping_resend` table:

```
+----+--------------------+----------+------------+---------+-------------+
| id | shipping_detail_id | quantity | createdAt  | product | first_print |
+----+--------------------+----------+------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 |                  1 |        1 | 2021-02-02 | A       |           1 |
|  2 |                  1 |        1 | 2021-02-03 | A       |           0 |
+----+--------------------+----------+------------+---------+-------------+
```

explanation :

1. this table contains information about how the detail for each product has sent, like example on the table above, first_print column has told us that if first_print = 1, then that is the first shipping, if 0 then that's not first shipping
2. from that table above, we know that product A has be sent on quantity 1 on '2021-02-02' and quantity 1 again in '2021-02-03'

My question is, how to find out quantity_hold, quantity_hold is quantity for each product that undelivered on 2021-02-02. undelivered is the condition where the product has still on our stock and not yet to be inserted on `shipping_resend` table

EXPECTED RESULTS should be like this on total_hold in '2021-02-02':

```
+---------+------------+
| product | total_hold |
+---------+------------+
| A       |          1 |
| B       |          1 |
+---------+------------+
```

i've tried with this

```
SELECT sd.product,
IF(sd.quantity != IFNULL(sd.quantity_send,0), (sd.quantity - IFNULL(sd.quantity_send,0)), NULL) AS total_hold

FROM 

shipping_details sd 
LEFT JOIN shipping_resend sr
ON sd.id = sp.shipping_detail_id
WHERE COALESCE((sr.createdAt BETWEEN '2021-02-02' AND '2021-02-03'),
           (sd.createdAt BETWEEN '2021-02-02' AND '2021-02-03'))

GROUP BY sd.product;
```

Comment: Share us the query you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sum the total shipped of each product and compare that to the total needing to be sent.

```
SELECT shipping_details.product
  ,shipping_details.quantity - COALESCE(total_shipped, 0) as total_hold
FROM shipping_details LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT product, SUM(quantity) as total_shipped
   FROM shipping_resend
   GROUP BY product) AS shipped
ON shipping_details.product = shipped.product
WHERE shipping_details.quantity - COALESCE(total_shipped, 0) > 0
```

The inner select totals the number of product sent, that is joined to the `shipping_details` table and compared with the number needing to be sent. If there's a difference you still have products to send.

I'm not sure your sample output is correct though, given the numbers in your tables. My query only returns product `B` as having stock held as the total of the `shipping_resend.quantity` for product `A` is 2.

Output

| product | total_hold |
| --- | --- |
| B | 1 |

If you need to know the status of the orders on a particular day, add a `WHERE` clause to the inner query

```
SELECT shipping_details.product
  ,shipping_details.quantity - COALESCE(total_shipped, 0) as total_hold
FROM shipping_details LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT product, SUM(quantity) as total_shipped
   FROM shipping_resend
   WHERE createdAt = '2021-02-02'
   GROUP BY product) AS shipped
ON shipping_details.product = shipped.product
WHERE shipping_details.quantity - COALESCE(total_shipped, 0) > 0
```

Output

| product | total_hold |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |

Comment: The A should be quantity_hold 1 because the other 1 based on shipping_resend is just sent on '2021-02-03' instead of what i want to find out is on '2021-02-02' so basically, the other 1 is still on hold because the remain stock are sent on '2021-02-03'

Comment: please take a look, i want to find out total_hold on date '2021-02-02' which is, it's just 1 to be sent on product A on that day, so it should be 1 other remaining to be total_hold because the shipping will be do on next day

Comment: So you want to filter the query for a particular day? In which case add a `WHERE` clause to the inner query.

Comment: sorry im new to MySQL, what happen if i dont input ```WHERE shipping_details.quantity - COALESCE(total_shipped, 0) > 0```

Comment: Are you asking if the where clause is required? Subtracting the amount shipped (`SUM(shipping_resend.quantity`) from the amount to be shipped (`shipping_details.quantity`) tells you what is left. If that is greater than zero the product needs to be included in the result set

Comment: Here's the SQL Fiddle I used: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/823a2f/6

Comment: thankyou sir for the queries and fiddle. it worked

Comment: sorry, maybe this is a silly question, if the product was not mentioned in ```shipping_resend```, is it defined by "Null" Values on quantity in shipping_resend like product B?

Comment: Using a `LEFT JOIN` means any product not in the `shipping_resend` table is still included but would return `null` for the `SUM(quantity)`. That's why I use `COALESCE` to set the value to zero.